# Importing CSV file to Google maps format

Tags: google-maps, import

I build a software that generate trails for my own use

I would like to test the software so I create A CSV file that contain the longitude and latitude  of the trail points

What is the format of a CSV file that can imported to Google maps

Answer (score 5):

[The documentation](https://support.google.com/mymaps/answer/3024836?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) isn't very specific about CSV files, so I just tried a bunch of formats.

Option 1 is to have separate latitude and longitude columns. You will be able to specify columns in the upload wizard.

```
lon,lat,title
-20.0390625,53.27835301753182,something
-17.841796875,53.27835301753182,something
```

Option 2 is to have a single coordinate column with the coordinates separated by space. You will be able to chose the order of the coordinate pair in the upload wizard.

[image]

```
lonlat,title
-20.0390625 53.27835301753182,something
-17.841796875 53.27835301753182,something
```

You'll also need one column that acts as the description for your points, it is, again, selectable in the wizard.

There seems to be no way to import CSVs as line geometries and no way to convert points to lines later on. Well-known-text (WKT) in the coordinate column fails to import.

The separator needs to be comma `,`. Semicolons `;`, spaces    and tabs don't work.

Comment: Hi chrki

Thx, that helped

I decide that a better format to load points to maps will be gpx files

I build a library for it and it load nicely with no question to google maps

Nachum